# Grid in angularjs which supports Server side filtering, Sorting & Pagination using Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-grid

I am in search of a **sample code/Project** of **AngularJS Grid Implementation** **with Server-side filtering, Sorting & Pagination** using **Spring MVC Hibernate**.

I could find many grids available in Internet. but If some can help me suggesting which is the best among it sharing your sample project will be really helpful.

Is ag-grid good option.[AG-Grid which I found through Browsing](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-tutorials/index.php)

Can you please give me reference of some sample code or Project, so that I can understand how to implement into a SPA application(Spring MVC + Hibernate).

Comment: ui-grid (http://ui-grid.info/) is the new ag-grid, I'd recommend that one.

Comment: I recommend for ui-grid, although annoying in long term. I think it would be faster to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, can anyone please share me a sample project which I can refer and implement.